# reflection of light and the uncertainty principle

Tags: visible-light, reflection, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I've heard that light reflects the same angle that it falls and so if we know the position of photon (the spot where it hits the surface) and the direction of where it shall go - that's violation of the uncertainty principle, so where is the mistake in reasoning?

Comment: The photon does not "bounce off" the surface, it is absorbed and reemitted. How do you think we can apply the uncertainty principle to that?

Comment: How do you want to measure the point at which the photon hits the surface? When you get around to actually specifying the method by which you would measure such a point in an experiment is where you'll find uncertainties popping up.

Comment: @ACuriousMind hmm, check [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/94765/43916)

Comment: @MonkeysUncle So if we have a laser which we can "make thinner" indefinitely and we point it to the mirror all of the sudden when the beam is thin enough it's reflection will start being uncertain, right?

Comment: Oh, interesting. But note that the answers to the question you linked essentially say that thinking about individual photons in the reflection process is...not a good, or well-defined, idea.

Comment: @ren You can't make a laser thinner indefinitely on the quantum scale. On a macroscopic scale we can think of a laser as a focused point of light because lasers are so much better than something like a flashlight. But as you make your beam very thin, you find that on a quantum scale there is still significant uncertainty in position. It is possible to essentially focus a laser to a point, but that point will have a very specific depth. You then lose information about the specific angle the photon approached the point from, or in other words the momentum of the photon.

Comment: For that matter, how are you measuring the vector momentum?  The photon energy can be determined quite well via fine-spectrum absorption but not the time of absorption, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple: you're dealing with an huge number of photons and you just know where the flux of photons is going. You don't know where the single photon is going and which is its momentum.

Also considers that, when the photon affect the surface, it is absorbed by the materials; after it is reemitted.

Comment: regarding reemition: check [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/94765/43916)

Comment: This is an aspect of the tunnel effect: the wave function of the photon goes inside the material and then is reflected back. The uncertain principle states that if we know certainly the position of a photon we don't know it's momentum (i.e. it's velocity). In your question you say that you know the position of the photon and it's direction: this is not correct. We know the direction of the ray of light, not the one of the single photon and not the position of the single photon. We don't know nothing about the momentum of the photon

Answer (score 1):

When you observe the reflection of light, you are dealing with a huge number of photons forming a beam with radius $\delta r$. Spot you see has non-zero dimension. So each photon has its own uncertainty in position. In addtion, since photons can vibrate around its propagation direction, they have  uncertainty in momentum (vector quantity). (Remember that you are observing the reflection in macroscopic view, so these uncertainties are nothing for you (very small)).

However, the uncertainty principle is not applied for the case above. This principle says that we cannot measure the position (x) and the momentum (p) of a particle with absolute precision. The more accurately we know one of these values, the less accurately we know the other. So, the uncertainty principle determines how well can we MEASURE canonical variables in the same time. When you attempt to measure position and momentum of photon, interaction happens and, as a result, it leads to larger uncertainty in momentum (large error in momentum measurement) if attempting to get higher accuracy in position measurement, and vice versa.

So, for two cases above, your argument is not true.