# Is the incident photon in a mirror, the same one that reflects?

Tags: optics, waves, wave-particle-duality

I am considering the photon as a particle.

The incident energy may be equal to the reflected energy, but I would like to know if there is any theory or way of demonstrating that the incident photon in a mirror may be exactly the same as it reflects.

Comment: Asking whether one particle is "the same" as any other only makes physical sense when there is something that can distinguish the particles. What possible difference do you see between two photons of the same frequency to do so in this case? Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83105/50583

Comment: possible answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94359/during-reflection-does-the-emitted-photon-have-same-properties

Comment: @Acuriousmind  I want to know if the incident photon may have been absorbed by the mirror and another emitted in its place, in the sequence, and in a very short time.

Comment: What difference does it make? What would distinguish the world where the photon was absorbed and another emitted from the world where "the same" photon comes back?

Comment: @ACuriousMind - I want to know if there is any process capable of identifying that there was an exchange of photons at the moment of reflection.

Comment: There is no answer to your question. You are assuming photons are distinguishable, but they are not.

Comment: @Felipe isn't your comment the answer? (except for the part about there being no answer).

Comment: My employer sends me a check for \$100, which I deposit in my bank account, bringing the total to \$1000.  The next day I send you a check for \$100.  Is that the same \$100 I got from my employer?  The question is meaningless.  Photons are not dollars, but the point is that asking whether two things are "the same" is not automatically a meaningful question.

Comment: @JEB I was talking about the question in the title.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, as there is only one photon involved.